# How to Dynamically Create Tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls, tabpage

This is in C#

I Need to basically make TabPages from a textbox.Text so for example:

```
textBox1.Text = "test";
TabPage textBox1.Text = new TabPage();
```

That is what i want to do.. i know that won't work directly, but that should give you the idea of how i want to create the tabPages.. then i want to be able to call them later on too so for example:

```
String browser = "browser 1";
(textBox1.Text as TabPage).Controls.Add(WebBrowser browser)
```

I need all the names to be dynamic because what this will be is a program that can run tests for customer accounts There would be a TabControl which has the "Account Number as the tabPage control name and then inside each of those tabPages would be another TabControl with a set up tabs with each invidivual test in it's own tab. So Tabs within Tabs basically.

Comment: TabPage textBox1.Text = new TabPage(); doesn't make any sense.Do you mean TabPage newpage = new TabPage { Name = textBox1.Text }; ?

Comment: I know TabPage textBox1.Text = new TabPage() doesnt make sense at all, thats the idea so sayign if textBox1.Text = "Test" it would infer the statement would be TabPage Test = new TabPage();... I need the tabPage to be created with the name of the textBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it look similar to this:

```
        var page = new TabPage(textBox1.Text);
        var browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        page.Controls.Add(browser);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);
        browser.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com");
        page.Select();
```

Comment: This created the tabPage, but it didn't actually select the tab

Comment: @Alex: You want tabControl1.SelectedTab = page;

Comment: Looks like that worked, i think this is what i need, but i'll need to do some tinkering... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Actually one other thing i want to know, How can i call on this Tab @ another time outside of this function?

This is basically what i turned out to look like.

```
String browserName = "Test Check";
var tabPageName = new TabPage(textBox1.Text);
var tabPageBrowser = new TabPage(browserName);
var tabPageTabControl = new TabControl();
var browser = new WebBrowser();
tabPageName.Controls.Add(tabPageTabControl);
tabPageTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPageBrowser);
tabPageBrowser.Controls.Add(browser);
mainTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPageName);
mainTabControl.SelectedTab = tabPageName;
```

Comment: Use variables or fields to hold a reference to the object you want to address later on. Dude, this is very basic stuff. Have a look at some tutorials. C# class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: The reason i ask is because if i try something like 


            MessageBox.Show(mainTabControl.SelectedTab.Name.ToString());

It comes up blank, so i dont see how i'm able to call that tab later on

Comment: That's because you aren't assigning a name to the new tab page control, you are only assigning text. In order for mainTabControl.SelectedTab.Name to return anything, you have to have tabPageName.Name = textBox1.Text;

Comment: nevermind, i had a brainfart... tabPageName.Name = textBox1.Text;