# Add New Tabs to a C# WinForms application from Templates?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Okay, so I have an application, written in Visual Studio 2013 C# using WinForms. On the application will be 3 buttons.

```
Add Tab Type A
Add Tab Type B
Add Tab Type C
```

Below these 3 buttons will be an empty TabControl. When someone clicks one of the above 3 buttons, I need the program to add a new Tab to the TabControl with a predefined layout. Each of the 3 buttons will produce a new tab with a different layout to the other 2 buttons.

WinForms does not seem to have a built in way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Dynamically Create Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737123/how-to-dynamically-create-tabs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I would tackle this like so:

Create your tab "Pages" as individual User Controls.

Then, your button click event would look something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage t = new TabPage();
    t.Controls.Add(new UserControl1() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm having an issue with this. I am using `t.name = tab_name` to declare the object name of the new tabpage. However, the system doesn't seem to be throwing an error when I try to make two new tabs with the same exact name. Whats going on?

Comment: That's quite normal; unlike variable names Name is not a Property that is required to be unique. So, if you want to use it, to identify the tabPage you'll need to ensure it is unique.